# MATLAB how to locate data cursor of graph to an exact place?

Tags: matlab

Hi currently I am trying to get certain points' time  on a graph(step response) with some certain amplitudes. I am using the data cursor but I am only able to drag it to the location. Is there any function that enables to automatically get the point given the amplitudes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) to select points on graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at function [datacursormode](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html), especially the part "Querying Data Cursor Mode": function `getCursorInfo` must be the function you are searching for.